# What is the proper way of using GPS Test Plus to update GPS data?

Tags: gps

Do you need to click the `Clear AGPS` button, then click the `Update AGPS` button, then wait for its home screen to update the list of satellites it finds, before closing the app?

Or is clicking the `Update AGPS` button sufficient?

The help file describes what these buttons do, but there doesn't seem to be any best practice for using the app (or when is the best time to close the app).

> **Clear AGPS Button.** Pressing this buttons clears the AGPS aiding data from your phone. Do this if your GPS takes a long time to get a
>   fix.
>
> **Update AGPS Button.** Pressing this button requests the download of AGPS aiding data. The AGPS aiding data can become out of date, so
>   requesting an update will get te latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating is sufficient. I think clear is for cases where you are offline and can not update.